# read from external file in a Minecraft Mod

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I would like to display some things on my screen with a mod and for that I want to write "Hello World" in *test.txt* (later will be json) and save it somewhere (?)  in my minecraft folders, so I do not need to recompile my mod to get this data;

What is the correct way to read this file from my mod and display it on my screen? I am using MCreator and only slowly begin to code *"custom elements"* and you can call me a total noob in programming java

What my idea is:

```
package net.mcreator.sant.gui.overlay;

import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.EventPriority;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.client.event.RenderGameOverlayEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.api.distmarker.OnlyIn;
import net.minecraftforge.api.distmarker.Dist;

import net.minecraft.world.World;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.PlayerEntity;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;

import net.mcreator.sant.SantModElements;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;
import io.netty.util.ResourceLeak;

@SantModElements.ModElement.Tag
public class ReadfromjsonOverlay extends SantModElements.ModElement {
    public ReadfromjsonOverlay(SantModElements instance) {
        super(instance, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void initElements() {
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
    }

    @OnlyIn(Dist.CLIENT)
    @SubscribeEvent(priority = EventPriority.NORMAL)
    public void eventHandler(RenderGameOverlayEvent event) {
        if (!event.isCancelable() && event.getType() == RenderGameOverlayEvent.ElementType.HELMET) {
            int posX = (event.getWindow().getScaledWidth()) / 2;
            int posY = (event.getWindow().getScaledHeight()) / 2;
            PlayerEntity entity = Minecraft.getInstance().player;
            World world = entity.world;
            int x = (int) entity.getPosX();
            int y = (int) entity.getPosY();
            int z = (int) entity.getPosZ();

            //here getting text and save it to "string"

            if ((true)) {
                Minecraft.getInstance().fontRenderer.drawString( string, posX + -151, posY + -63, -1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(code generated by MCreator)

Please help anyone I am totally stucked with this

Comment: I would suggest asking on [their forums](https://mcreator.net/forum) as you'll want to use their software, it wouldn't much help to you if we gave you code that you wouldn't understand. If you fancy learning, try this [W3 tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_files.asp).

Comment: @Lucan yeah, thanks; though I already know how to read from files, but minecraft does not allow to use some parts of java, that are in no way connected to minecraft, like copying into clipboard etc... And yeah, I thought, maybe getting ready code will make me learn more, because I am always trying to understand some code before I use it

Comment: Minecraft does not prevent you from executing code 'not connected to minecraft'. If it's a simple config you're after, there are [tutorials](https://cadiboo.github.io/tutorials/1.15.1/forge/3.3-config/) for that. Otherwise, update your question with what you've tried; see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Lucan, oh that is exactly what I was looking for, I idi not have an idea of setting up a config file, thanks dude, answer the question and earn some reputation )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Forge's `ForgeConfigSpec` as an easy route for a config. There's a tutorial [here](https://cadiboo.github.io/tutorials/1.15.1/forge/3.3-config/).

Most configuration files in Forge utilise [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) so it's worth [understanding](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yaml/yaml_basics.htm).

W3Schools has a good [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_files_create.asp) on general File IO which is worth a read if it's not a config you're after.